# Ouput numbers *2 using while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

My program is supposed to take an input and then multiply each number by 2 until it reaches the input number. For instance, if the number inputted is 8 it would output 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128. My code is stopping at the number 8 instead of going to 128. UNANSWERED STILL

```
limit = input('Enter a value for limit: ')
limit = int(limit)
ctr = 1
while ctr <= (limit):
    print(ctr, end=' ')
    ctr = ctr * 2
print("limit =", limit )
```

Comment: I am brand new to this and I also want to do this without the ** operator

Comment: Well, think about your condition: `while ctr <=(limit)`, it's doing exactly what you've told it to do. You should really use a `for` loop for this, anyway.

Comment: you're mixing up value and counter.

Comment: whats the point of `powers= (limit)*2`? Its not even used

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I need to do it in a while loop even if a for loop is the better way to do it

Comment: @abccd i am supposed to run powers through a seperate variable. But i dont think its doing anything

Comment: But you aren't running it through anything. You've declared it as `(limit)*2`, but then you don't use it anywhere.

Your counter I assume is meant to increase by 1 each loop, from 1 to 8, and your power should multiply by 2 each loop from 1 to 128

Comment: @smead so my ctr should be ctr=ctr+1? And then for the powers=(limit)*2, would powers go inside the while loop?

Comment: yeah, but i assume you want the power to start at 1, and not `limit*2` which should be your last number

Comment: @smead I dont understand. So what would my powers variable be then?

Comment: you need one variable that starts at 1, and gets increased by 1 each loop. then you need another variable that starts at 1, and gets multiplied by 2 each loop. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You're multiplying `ctr` by 2, but comparing it to 8, so it goes from 1, to 2, to 4, to 8, then stopping.

I'm not sure why you want to do this without the ** operator, but in that case you may have to think about keeping track of the counter (from 1 to 8) and the value (from 1 to 128) as two separate variables.

Comment: i am confused with what you mean by adding a second variable for it

Answer (score 0):

Look again at your `while` condition: your loop runs until your product reached the user's input. In your example, `limit` will be set to 8 and your loop will end when `ctr` reaches 8. Here, I'll add some comments to your code and maybe you can see where the issue you're running into is:

```
limit = input('Enter a value for limit: ')
limit = int(limit) # Getting input from the user. If the user enters n,
                   # the program should output powers of 2 up to 2^n
ctr = 1            # Initializing the variable holding the powers of 2
while ctr <= (limit):  # While the power of 2 is less than n (This line is
                       # where your problem is. Your loop ends when the
                       # power of 2 reaches n, not 2^n)
    print(ctr, end=' ') # Print the power of 2
    ctr = ctr * 2      # Double the power of 2 to get the next one
print("limit =", limit ) # Print the number the user put in
```

To fix this, either use a separate variable for your loop counter and your product, or better yet use a for loop:

```
for i in range(limit):
    ctr *= 2
```

Comment: I am confused with what you mean by adding another variable with it

Comment: One variable counts how many times the loop has run, and you stop the loop when it reaches some value. (In your case, `limit`). Another value holds your result as you're multiplying it by 2. The gist of it is that right now, your loop will stop once you reach the number the user put in, and not after having run that many times.

Comment: could you please look at the edit i did to my code? I am stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: @BigMan_13 It looks like you've already sorted out your infinite loop issue, but have a look at the edit I made to my answer and see if that helps you figure out where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop stops when it reaches 8, as given in your condition.

```
while ctr <=(limit)
```

You can simply achieve the result by using following code.

```
l = int(input())
n = 1
while l>0:
    print(n)
    n *= 2
    l -= 1
```

I hope this answers the query.